# Shopping cart system testing

Tags: untagged

Can anyone recommend a service or application that will go through the process of conducting a test transaction on an ecommerce site? I would like to set my store into test mode, then just let a bot hammer through it, enter sample customer info, and complete the checkout. ab meets Mozenda meets Magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of scripted solution that's worth the bother, simply because it's predictable and that's not what you need. This may sound silly but you could do a lot worse than getting school kids involved. Kids have a knack of attacking systems differently to what they are intended to withstand, which tends to find breaking points you may never even have considered. A local company made arrangements with the local high school, which made it part of a class IT project. The instructions were simple: See what you can break.

Answer (score 1):

Using the scripting language of your choice, you could interface with Selenium-RC, which will allow you to hijack a browser and step through the e-commerce application, inserting your random data as necessary.

Selenium IDE will let you record a web transaction and play it back, if you want to test with more or less the same data every time.

- http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/
- http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

Comment: This is a good idea. The answer from John made me realize that it probably isnt a task that needs to be automated.